# Error: The required scopes are not authorized

Tags: python

Team,
I am new to python and requests library. Need help as I am getting the
'error': 'The required scopes are not authorized'.
First Step: getting access token. I am getting access token.

```
import requests
import json


print(requests.certs.where())

myToken = 'https://........./internal/access_token'

headers = {
           "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

data = {
    "grant_type": 'client_credentials',
  "scope": 'api-customer-migration',
  "client_id": 'VariantConfigureclientApp',
  "client_secret": 'vc@123A!'
    }


response = requests.post(myToken, headers = headers,data=data,verify=False)
jsonResponse = response.json()
#print('jsonResponse: ' + str(jsonResponse))
output_1 = jsonResponse.get('access_token')
output_str=str(output_1)
print('output_str: ' + output_str)
```

The above code is working and I am getting the access token.
Now I am using this access code to Post request to post the data.
Second Step: sending POST request. continuation code as below.

```
end_point='https://............../customers/examplenumber'

data1= {
"addressType": "V",
"action": "N",
"businessPartner": "0000111111",
"ifaNumber": "",
"name1": "Systems Inc.",
"name2": "",
"name3": "",
"postalCode": "95165-1700",
"poBox": "",
"postalCodePOB": "",
"cityPoBox": "",
"street": "560 W sample Dr",
"street2": "",
"city": "San Jose",
"country": "US",
"region": "CA",
"duns": "",
"name1I": "",
"name2I": "",
"name3I": "",
"streetI": "",
"street2I": "",
"cityI": "",
"regionI": "",
"cityPoBoxI": "",
"salesTaxId": "",
"companyPostalCode": ""
     }

headers_2 = { "Content-Type":"application/json",
              "Authorization": f"Bearer {output_str}",
                           "grant_type":"authorization_code",
              "scope": 'api-customer',
                  "client_id": 'VariantConfigureclientApp',
  "client_secret": 'vc@123A!'}

response = requests.post(end_point, data=data1, headers=headers_2,verify=False)
print(response)
print(response.json())
```

**NOTE:** I have suppressed the SSL validation by passing verify=False for now.

When I execute the code, I am getting the below error:

**<Response [403]>
{'error': 'The required scopes are not authorized'}**

Comment: It means you don't have permission to access the page. Perhaps talk to your web admins to see if you do have the correct permissions first.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I will check with our Admin

Comment: Before going to Admin, I used postman from the same box and it works fine. But I am getting error with Python script.

Comment: With the same access token?

Comment: Yes, it is the same access token.